# How to Identify scope object has a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to identify with the format of the scope variable, whether it has a value or not?

I have a scope as `$rootScope.responseAllFilters.selectedCodeFrames`:

1. First the list is empty as shown below -

   Empty scope:

   [image]
2. Now we select and deselect some checkboxes and the data is entered as shown below -

   Scope has data

   [image]:

I am unable to identify at first whether we have any key-value pair in it with hasOwnProperty. Is there any other way to identify?

Comment: you can use `Object.keys($rootScope.responseAllFilters.selectedCodeFrames)`. this will give array. if you don't have any values this array length will be zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Object.keys($rootScope.responseAllFilters.selectedCodeFrames)`. this will give array. if you don't have any values this array length will be zero